# create a table from result of command

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to do is get some lines from output logs, split the data into different columns like **Brand, Product, Quantity** etc...all the information for these 3 columns get can be obtained from our logs using

```
grep 'ITEMS_SOLD Today' /tmp/$$.items
```

This command results something like

```
XXXXXXXX ITEMS_SOLD Today for XXXX "brandname"."productname1" XXXX items sold : 123. 
XXXXXXXX ITEMS_SOLD Today for XXXX "brandname"."productname2" XXXX items sold : 345.
XXXXXXXX ITEMS_SOLD Today for XXXX "brandname"."productname3" XXXX items sold : 678.
```

Now I want to get the input for my columns from these lines(there can be N number of lines) and create a table structure which I can send over mail.Position of "brandname"."productname" is 11th and quantity (eg 123) is 18th from the beginning of the line.

My required result is

```
*Brand  Product  Quantity*

Brand  product1    123
Brand  product2    345
Brand  product3    567
```

I am able to split the "Brandname.productname" by removing quotes and delimiter ".".

```
var=`grep 'ITEMS_SOLD Today' /tmp/$$.items |awk '{gsub(/["]/, "", $11);sub(/\./, " ", $11);print $11}'`
echo "$var"
```

result is

```
Brand product1
Brand Product2
Brand product3

quantity=`grep 'ITEMS_SOLD Today' /tmp/$$.items |awk '{print $18}'`
echo "quantity"
```

result is

```
123
345
678
```

But I am not sure how to put into table.Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F\" -v OFS='|' 'BEGIN { print "*Brand", "Product", "Quality*"} { sub(/.* : /, "", $5); sub(/[.]/, "", $5); print $2, $4, $5 }' file | column -t -s '|'
```

Output:

```
*Brand     Product       Quality*
brandname  productname1  123
brandname  productname2  345
brandname  productname3  678
```

- Using `column -t` for formatting is better than using `printf`.
- Remove `BEGIN { print "*Brand", "Product", "Quality*"}` if you don't need the header.

Comment: This is what `awk` was built for

Comment: first two columns its working fine, but third column I am nt getting desired output.in Quality column I am getting like "XXXXXXXXXX Items sold: 123" all the text that is present after product name is coming in 3rd column. It would be helpful if you explain how you are considering $2, $$ and $5.

Comment: Does the part `items sold :` really have a space on it or not? Because if it doesn't, `sub(/.* : /, "", $5)` should just be `sub(/.*: /, "", $5)`.

Comment: Each field or column is separated by `"` as specified by `-F`. The needed columns are the 2nd, the 4th and the 5th which are $2, $4 and $5 respectively. $2 and $4 is not needed to be reformatted, but $5 needs some of its characters deleted. We use `sub` for it.

Comment: only "Brandname"."product" is inside quotes..other text in the line is not having quotes.items sold is separated by a space,but no quotes.and also items sold is not immediately followed by product name.there is some text inbetween.123 (quantity) is the last word in the line.can you try getting last word..it might be easy.

Comment: @ManasaJ Can you post a raw file in `pastebin.com`? I want to examine the actual format of it.

Comment: Try this instead: `awk -F\" -v OFS='|' '{ sub(/[. \t\r]*$/, "", $5); sub(/.*[ \t]/, "", $5); print $2, $4, $5 }' file | column -t -s '|'`

Comment: This is working fine. I could get the desired result.But one small issue,when there is only one line in the result of grep command, both table header and data are coming in the same line. Other than this everything is fine.

Comment: You can modify the BEGIN block to insert a line with an invisible character after it so it would not get deleted when you run with `column -t`: `BEGIN { print "*Brand", "Product", "Quality*"; printf "\x01\n" }`.